# Check if an element appears in an array during the projection stage of a mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I've got a collection of mongo documents like -

```
{
    "_id" : "c959e4d6-961d-4043-ade6-2f93aa055e11",
    "events" : [
        "clickOut"
        "showHoverAd",
        "closeHoverAd"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "d0dcb2be-f8bc-45cd-8337-d89a16063b08", 
    "events" : [ 
        "zoom",
        "pan"
    ] 
}
{
    "_id" : "9179b26e-e45c-48ab-93f6-e73b8ebe559b",
    "events" : [
        "clickOut"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "db0b82ad-7a33-4ce8-9117-f6ecf041d0d9",
    "events" : [
        "adjustStars",
        "adjustPrice",
        "closeHoverAd",
        "showHoverAd"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to use a projection stage in an aggregation pipeline to identify if a particular string appears in the events field.

```
db.events.aggreate([
    {$project: {
        session: '$_id',
        clickedOut: {
            $cond: [{$elemMatch: {'$events':'clickOut'}},true,false]
        }
    }}
])
```

I'm getting an error - `exception: invalid operator '$elemMatch'`.

I want my output documents to look like -

```
{
    "session" : "c959e4d6-961d-4043-ade6-2f93aa055e11",
    "clickedOut" : false
}
{ 
    "session" : "d0dcb2be-f8bc-45cd-8337-d89a16063b08", 
    "clickedOut" : true
}
```

But I can't seem to find a way of doing it. I've tried using `$in` and `$all` or simply

```
$cond: {'$events':'clickOut'}
```

but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following aggregation:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$events"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "session": "$_id",
            "clickedOut": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$events", "clickOut" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$session",
            "count": {
                "$sum": "$clickedOut"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "session": "$_id",
            "clickedOut": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$count", 1 ] }, true, false ]
            }            
        }
    },
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "session" : "db0b82ad-7a33-4ce8-9117-f6ecf041d0d9",
            "clickedOut" : false
        }, 
        {
            "session" : "9179b26e-e45c-48ab-93f6-e73b8ebe559b",
            "clickedOut" : true
        }, 
        {
            "session" : "d0dcb2be-f8bc-45cd-8337-d89a16063b08",
            "clickedOut" : false
        }, 
        {
            "session" : "c959e4d6-961d-4043-ade6-2f93aa055e11",
            "clickedOut" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: It seems so simple when you see it! Thanks!

Comment: @AidanEwen You can say that again! At first sight I thought that was a walk in the park until I had to figure out how to project the boolean values :-)